# OpenSC 0.20.0 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: 18.04, smartcard

is there any plan to update the [OpenSC package in Ubuntu 18.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/opensc) from version 0.17.0 to version 0.20.0?
(I'm new here. Sorry if this is the wrong place to ask)

Background:

- Our software is based on OpenSC. Due to an unknown problem, OpenSC 0.17.0 does not work for us. However, OpenSC 0.20.0 works just fine.
- Our customer wants to stick to using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, so updating to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is not an option

Thanks in advance, Felix

Comment: In all likelihood, it won't be updated. You might try requesting a backport, but you'd probably need to help with testing the backported package.

Comment: Hi muru, thanks for the super quick reply. I think that answers my question.